# Accessing redux store via child component in react native

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am using Redux with React Native and I'm having problem in accessing a specific index of the redux store array with the key.

Here's a rough idea of what I'm trying to do. I have a `ParentComponent` that accesses the reduxStore for a state `data` and `data` contains an array of `id`,`title` in it.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {

  dataArray() {
    return Object.keys(this.props.data).map(key => this.props.data[key])
  }
  /*
    Consider the dataArray has elements which are an array of `id` & `title` 
  */

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.fragmentContainer}>
        {this.dataArray().map((element) => {
          return 
          <ChildComponent
            key={element.id}
            id={element.id} />
        })}
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }

}
```

Now I wanna access `title` of each element of the array via the `ChildComponent`. This is what I'm trying to do to access it:

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {
  render(
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.data[this.props.id].title}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  )
}
```

Obviously the above doesn't work. It's just an idea of what I'm trying to do. I am unable to access the redux store `data` using a given `key`. I tried to find out how one can access it but I found no solution. Is my method of accessing the state for the `ChildComponent` wrong. Can anyone refer me to how I can achieve this?

NOTE: I specifically want to access the state via the `ChildComponent`. If that's not how it's supposed to work like, please refer me to some other way or some documentation that explains how this is supposed to be done.

Answer (score 0):

If your child component is a class component, you can import `connect`, set up your reducer in `mapStateToProps` and bind them in your `export`.

You can also send the reducer prop value as props from parent to child component. Something like this `<Child value={this.props.myData} />`. Now in your child component you can refer it as `this.props.value`. If you use this approach, it doesn't matter if your child is a class component or not. Don't forget to also instance `value` in your child component creation.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't see you passing a `data` prop from your parent to child. Thus you won't get `this.props.data` in your child component.

I don't understand why would you want to extract `title` that way when you can pass it as a prop just like you passed `id`.

If you specifically want to access redux store, then you use `connect` from `react-redux`.

Here's a link to see how to do that
http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html